Is there a model for facial detection based on an infrared camera?
I need an AI model for facial detection based on an infrared camera

Is there an existing model for this with per-trained weights?

Does this model work well when the lighting conditions may change rapidly or drastically, i.e. through normalization or something?



Hi. Asking for per-trained models may be off-topic. See our on-topic page. We can discuss this on meta again (if necessary). However, you may not just be interested in per-trained models but any (untrained) model suitable for this task, so I think your question would be on-topic.

Well yes and no. A model is only as good as the data you give it, it really depends on your data and what data you have as well as. I can provide you a pre-trained infrared machine learning repository https://github.com/maxbbraun/thermal-face <- It's here, but implementation is a different story.
If you know how you're going to implement it then badaboom my job here is done.

You can train a model by yourself if you have a dataset based on mtcnn architecture...

you can try the model from this git repo (this is for thermal cameras but it is a good reference so i have mentioned it ignore it if you don't find any thing important from this one )
=> https://github.com/xyth0rn/ThermalFaceDetection
It explains very well documentation about face detection in thermal cameras.
and if you want to train your custom model for face detection you can try this one repo
=> https://github.com/avshet/Face-recognition-in-Near-InfraRed-images.git
